# How to translate PARTITION BY with a FIRST_VALUE() in linq?

Tags: oracle, linq, partition-by

It should resolve with a group by, in all rows of the result must load the first value, that will repeat in each group

[image]

I tried with a group by

Comment: Please read [ask]. And please do not post code as images, and ideally add a [mre] and what have you tried.

Comment: Also note that while LINQ allows you to write a wide range of queries, still it is not suitable for every task, especially taking in account different database types and their support.